# How to target and replace script tag without id or class

Tags: javascript

I have code of something like this:

```
 line 041: <script src='http://blabla041' type='text/javascript'></script>
 line 052: <script src='http://blabla052' type='text/javascript'></script>
 line 063: <script src='http://blabla053' type='text/javascript'></script>
 ...
 line 499: <script src='http://specificaddress' type='text/javascript'></script>
 ...
 line 997: <script src='http://blabla097' type='text/javascript'></script>
 line 998: <script src='http://blabla098' type='text/javascript'></script>
 line 999: <script src='http://blabla099' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

And I can edit this only with classic JavaScript.

And the question is how can I target this script tag with src of `http://specificaddress` to delete it completely?

Comment: Loop through the script elements, and look at what their src attribute contains ...? Be aware though that removing an existing script element won't "reverse" the execution of code that was already executed at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found out what was wrong in my code.

**Important**: You have to enter an entire path for a specified script.

```js
var script = document.getElementsByTagName('script');

for (var i = 0; i < script.length; i++) {
  if (script[i].src == 'file:///C:/Users/username/Desktop/test.js') {
    script[i].src = 'nothingHere';
    console.log(script[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src='file:///C:/Users/username/Desktop/test.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='js/adawdaw.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, but something is not working... I tried exactly as you posted and also tried to replace the "specifiedadress" with full url like this "http://specificaddress", but this didn't help. It didn't removed it

Answer (score 0):

**For example on 098**

```
let element = document.querySelector("script[src='http://blabla098']");
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it exactly as you said and tried to set also timeout for a 3 seconds to make sure it is executed after, but this didn't removed it.

Comment: As you can see in my screenshot of my codepen, you can see that after "line 998" there is no script... https://puu.sh/rOyA0/318561fc26.png

This is the codepen I made: http://codepen.io/InstaK/pen/wzQJbO

Answer (score 0):

this is one of the present solutions

```
    function scriptElement(param){
    var sc = document.scripts;
    for(var i=0;i<sc.length;i++){
      if(sc[i].src == param || sc[i].id == param){
        document.scripts[i].index = i;
        return document.scripts[i];
      }
     if(sc[i].className == param){
      return document.scripts;
       }

    }
    }
    scriptElement("http://blabla041").index;//return index => 0
    scriptElement("http://blabla041").src; // return http://blabla041
    scriptElement("http://blabla041").className; //return class attribute
    scriptElement("http://blabla041").id; // return id;
    scriptElement("scriptid").src;//also className,id
    scriptElement("classname")[0].index;//also src,className,id

    //to replace src
    scriptElement("http://blabla041").src = "http://newsrc.url";
    //to remove script
    scriptElement("http://blabla041").parentNode.removeChild(scriptElement("http://blabla041"));
```